# Too many initializers for array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to initialize an array in Visual C++.

In my header file, I am declaring the array like this.
`int pawnSquareTable[64];`

In the cpp file where I include the header file, I am initializing the array in the constructor of the class in this manner:

`pawnSquareTable[64]={0,0,1,2.....64 values};`

However, VC++ is giving me a `Too many initializer values`error. Why is this happening?

EDIT:
The red squiggly line underlines the second element of the array.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to *assign* to an array. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: What is MCVE? I don't know that. Yes, I am trying to assign values in the constructor.

Comment: Your array size is `64` and you are probably initializing it more elements.

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, what is the *complete* declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A::A()
    // : pawnSquareTable{1,2,3,4} // this would compile in clang/gcc
{
    // for MSVC, instead do this
    int* p = pawnSquareTable;
    for( int i : {1,2,3,4} ) // <- values here
        *p++=i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have the code `pawnSquareTable[64]={0,0,1,2.....64 values};` in your constructor, you are actually trying to set the value for the single element `pawnSquareTable[64]` (65th element of the array). The compiler expects to get an int and not an initializer-list, that's the reason for the error.

Instead of doing it, you should initialize the array in constructor's initialization list:

```
A::A() : pawnSquareTable{ 0, 1, 2 } //fill your values
{
}
```

Comment: No, that would be 65th element.

Comment: he's using Visual C++., it does not support explicit initializer for arrays

Comment: I need to initialise around 5-6 arrays, and 5 constant variables. It will look ugly if I put them in the initialiser list. Is there any other method?